# Excel checkboxes are not updating linked cells when changed with VBA

Tags: excel, checkbox, excel-2016, vba

I have a file with checkboxes on it that need to be cleared out on open. I am using a module that loops through a For Each loop to set all og the checkboxes to FALSE. The issue is that they are not updating the linked cells with the new values and the cell remain empty. Can I add some code to the loop to force each checkbox to update any linked cells?

```
Sub ClearCheckBoxes()
    Dim cb As Excel.CheckBox
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        cb.Value = False
    Next cb
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: When you ask a question, provide some code you already have, so that other can help you.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the post.